# Weak topology on $L^p,~p> 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

How looks like the weak topology in the particular case  $X=L^p$, I mean, is possible to detail this topology beyond standar form:

> Arbitrary union of finite intersections  open pre-images of opens in the real line?

Comment: Since $X:=L^p[0,1]$ is reflexive and separable weak topology of the unit ball is metriazable. The formula for the metric is given by $d(f,g)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} |H_n(f_n-g_n)|$, where $(H_n)$ is norm dense in the unit ball of $(L_p)^*=L_q$. Since [Haar system](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Haar_system) $(h_n)$ is a basis of $L_q$, by taking linear combinnations of $(h_n)$ you can get quite explicit but useless descrpiption of the weak topology of the unita ball of $L_p$.